# After execute the code in $stateChangeStart state should be changed

Tags: angularjs

I am using $stateChangeStart under call back function I am getting the details of user from database if their is any user in the session that will rout to particular state otherwise It will rout to login

```
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        getSessionData(function(status, data){
          if(status){
            var user = data
            if(toState.authenticate && !user){
              // User isn’t authenticated
              $state.go("login");
              event.preventDefault(); 
            }
          }
          else{
            $state.go("login");
            event.preventDefault(); 
          }  
        })
        function getSessionData(callBack){
          sessionsFactry.getSession.query(function(p_objResp){
            //console.log(p_objResp);
            if(p_objResp.success)
              callBack(p_objResp.success, p_objResp.data)
            else
              callBack(p_objResp.success, '')         
          });
        }
      })
```

while login and rout changes its working fine when the user logout and press back on browser continuously its taking time to check the user and redirecting to login page. How that can be overcome?
Thank you,
Babji.

Comment: I removed my answer because it wasn't helpful. You need to inject the user details to the controller using resolve. Read this [tutorial](http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/12/09/authentication-made-simple-in-single-page-angularjs-applications.html) on how it should be done the right way

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did like which was shown in that url, but my requirement is the users may contain different roles, So before changing the state i should know the roles of current user(present in session) so i am sending request to url and getting details from database, Before getting those details its redirecting and when the execution of getting details complete its changing state to logging (if no user found in session